# Permission error with ASP Classic on IIS using copyFile

Tags: file, asp-classic, jscript

I'm writing a repository in ASP classic (using JScript) running on IIS 7.0 and I'm having some trouble with permission when moving files around. I have to following generic function that always gives me a permission denied error.

```
function moveFile(source, target){
    fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    newloc = target + "\\" + source.name;
    debug("Copying file: " + source.path + " to " + newloc);
    fs.copyFile(source.path, Server.MapPath( "repository/" ), true);

}
```

When I call the function with with source `source.path` being `D:\Inetpub_EXT\wwwroot\builder\repo\dump\alicia.docx` and target being `D:\Inetpub_EXT\wwwroot\builder\repo\repository` I get the following output:

```
Treating dumpfile: alicia
Copying file: D:\Inetpub_EXT\builder\repo\dump\alicia.docx to 
D:\Inetpub_EXT\wwwroot\builder\repo\repository
Microsoft JScript runtime error '800a0046'
Permission denied
```

I've verified that both the folder and file exist and I gave full control to IIS_WPG, IUSR, Authenticated User, System and Administrators in builder.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your permissions. Be careful of assumptions.

For example you may be assuming that if the IIS user has permissions on the `builder` directory, then it has permissions on all subdirectories. This is not a good assumption. 
If you set the ACL on the `builder` directory to give IIS permissions, after having created the subdirectories, then those subdirectories won't automatically inherit the permissions that you later applied to `builder`.

You can use icacls.exe from the command line to view the permissions:

```
 %windir\system32\icacls.exe  d:\inetpub\wwwroot\builder\foo\bar
```